# Rails polymorphic inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, polymorphic-associations

I have models Company, Person and Task. Company has many tasks, person has many tasks, task belongs to company and task belongs to person. So there is polymorphic association between them.
I want to create a form for adding a new task where I can select either company or person for task to belong to. I'm looking for something like autocomplete input that works with polymorphic association. Is there any generally used solution?

**Update**

I'm trying to use TokenInput now. But there is a very strange problem with it.
I wrote for both Company and Person models:

```
def token
  "#{id}_#{self.class.name}"
end
```

Then I render contacts.json like that

```
[
    {"name":"My company","token":"1_Company"},
    {"name":"The Person","token":"1_Person"}
]
```

Then I initialize TokenInput:

```
$('.token-input').tokenInput '/contacts.json'
    tokenLimit: 1
    tokenValue: "token"
```

Autocomplete works pretty well but it sends to params empty string!
And the most strange thing: when I add this to tokenInput options:

```
propertyToSearch: "token"
```

it works! I mean, the value "contact: 1_Person" appears in params. But it crushes the appearance of my input cause there are "1_Person", "1_Company" values instead of "My company", "The Person" in autocomplete. Maybe anyone know how to fix it?

**Update 2**

Oh wow! I downloaded the last version of TokenInput from github (I've downloaded it from loopj.com before) and it works!

Nonetheless, it would be fine to know another solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any general solution but my 2 cents goes to: [TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/).
Server return something like:

```
[
   {"id":"3", "name":"Mark", "item_type": "Person" },
   {"id":"34", "name":"IBM",  "item_type": "Task"}
]
```

Client side you have to build a hidden input field where to store item_type. And that is. 
There are some problem if Person and Company have same ids but it can be solved in using a *prefix* to id field and stripping that with javascript before sending (**BIG HACK**).

Or maybe you can simply use two different input fields.

Searching on github i found this plugin [Rails-token-input](https://github.com/vredniy/rails-token-input) but I don't know it.

But

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've read the original article of the Rails-token-input's author but his solution doesn't work properly for me. I updated my question.